# How to organize percentage values on top of a stacked bar chart ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a very skewed bar chart in ggplot2.

Here's the dput text output:

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "Average", "B", "C", "D", 
"E"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Undiscounted", "Discounted"
), class = "factor"), value = c(18453601.4400001, 11941354.11, 
10748756.04, 6488253.74000001, 6078914.73000002, 2509377.50173653, 
1157538776.56, 833907589.89, 674006380.96, 574466340.26, 534854603.27, 
13191411.5509581)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), .Names = c("Name", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's the code I use to plot it:

```
library(ggplot2)
  text_size= 18
  label_bottom_size=18
  plot1<- ggplot(df1, aes(x = Name, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
    ggtitle(sprintf("Bar chart of Stuff" ))+
    theme(axis.title=element_text(size=text_size))+
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=text_size+20))+
    theme(axis.text.x= element_text(size=label_bottom_size))+
    theme(axis.text.y= element_text(size=text_size))+
    theme(legend.text = element_text(size=text_size))+
    theme(legend.title = element_text(size=text_size))
```

As some of the bar charts are so small and text doesn't fit, what I want to do is just have a (X%/Y%) above each bar that shows the percentage breakout. The values shown are in dollars.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you overwrite `theme` so many times? What's wrong to put everything in one `theme`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, nothing -- new to ggplot2 and so I just added some pluses when I needed new stuff. Does it make a difference though? It doesn't impact what I'm trying to do right?

Comment: @user1357015 you can put all `theme` stuff in one `theme` part, just seperate them with comma's; putting it together in one `theme` doesn't impact what you're trying to do

Comment: @Jaap, ah ok, I'll do that from now one -- but what about my actual question? How do I get that going?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is some hack using `data.table` for aggregating the data and then displaying it with `geom_text` (there are probably better ways though)

```
library(data.table)
temp <- data.table(df1)[, per := (value/sum(value))*100, by = Name]
temp <- temp[, list(value = sum(value), 
                    per = paste(sprintf("%.02f%%", per), collapse = " / "),
                    variable = variable), by = Name]

library(ggplot2)
text_size= 18
label_bottom_size=18
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Name, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  ggtitle(sprintf("Bar chart of Stuff" ))+
  theme(axis.title=element_text(size=text_size),
  plot.title=element_text(size=text_size+20),
  axis.text.x= element_text(size=label_bottom_size),
  axis.text.y= element_text(size=text_size),
  legend.text = element_text(size=text_size),
  legend.title = element_text(size=text_size)) +
  geom_text(data = temp, aes(x = Name, y = value, label = per), vjust=-0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to multiply your percents by 100.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: That was pretty neat. Thanks!

Comment: I would describe this as the correct way to do it, not a hack at all.